# Thymeleaf - set resource message from javascript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf. There is no problem with displaying the resource message when the page is first opened. But I am having a problem when I want to re-render the inside of select after ajax request.

Html(first load):

```
<select onchange="destLangChanged()" class="no-round-input-bg" id="destLang">
    <option value="en" th:utext="#{lang.en}"></option>
    <option value="fr" th:utext="#{lang.fr}"></option>
</select>
```

Javascript side:

```
var $el = $("#destLang");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$el.append($("<option></option>")
.attr("th:utext", "[[#{lang.en}]]").attr("value", '#{lang.en}'));
```

As you can see I tried both with two different methods without both "[[# {}]]" and "# {}".

at the end of this code, I am expecting for '#destLang'  to be emptied and adding the value of lang.en from resource. but the result is as follows.Option is added but resource message is not displayed properly

[image]

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: You don't have access to server variables in the browser. Thymeleaf can only do something for you on the server, never in the browser. Adding an attribute like `th:utext` with the help of JS will literally do **nothing at all** except adding that attribute. There is no way to make that work like you think it would.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @connexo's comment.

Lets first think about, what is thymeleaf and how it works. Thymeleaf is a templating language which can bind values (both way, HTML to Java object, Java object to HTML). These templated files are stored in resource folder and whenever client asked for these files, server run these templates with necessary java objects to resolve the final HTML. In the final generated HTML you never see thymeleaf attributes. Browser does not understand these attributes. So thyemleaf attributes are resolved in server side.

So these thymeleaf attributes you are adding is not resolved by server side, that is why, doing so in javascript is not reflecting as it were reflecting while modifying original template files.

Hopes it shed a light upon your question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, with a default Spring Boot/Thymeleaf application, you can use `..?lang=fr` to change the used locale. So instead of trying to do something in JavaScript, you can add something like this:

```
<a th:href="@{/(lang=en)}">English</a>
<a th:href="@{/(lang=fr)}">Français</a>
```